# How to efficiently filter and extract data from a pandas dataframe into an array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe  df_orders such as this:

```
    Symbol    action    orderid   qty    status   price
    AAPL      buy       1232131   100    open     110.41
    MSFT      sell      8120472   200    open     83.42
    MSFT      sell      8120473   500    open     81.12
```

I want to get orderid, qty, status and price for each row where 'Symbol' == 'MSFT' and 'Action' == 'sell' and put them into an array.  Desired output is

```
[['MSFT','sell',8120472,200,'open',83.42],['MSFT','sell',8120473,200,'open',81.12]]
```

I wrote the following code a while ago that works, but it is not efficient.  I need to run this piece of code at least 50 million times per day and a very millisecond counts.

```
myarray = []
dfsells = df_orders[df_orders['Symbol'] == symbol]
if len(dfsells.index) > 0:
    dfsells = dfsells[dfsells['action'] == 'Sell']
    dfsells = dfsells.reset_index(drop=True)

    if len(dfsells.index) > 0:
        for j in range(0,len(dfsells.index)):
                orderid = dfsells.loc[j,'orderid']
                sellqty = dfsells.loc[j,'qty']
                status = dfsells.loc[j,'status']
                price = round(float(dfsells.loc[j,'price']),2)
                myarray.append([symbol,'sell',orderid,sellqty,status,price])
```

What is the quickest way to get this array?

Comment: you can just write `df.loc[(df.Symbol=='MSFT' | df.Action=='sell, [list of features you like].values`

Answer (score 1):

```
df[(df['Symbol'] == symbol) & (df['action'] == 'Sell')].values.tolist()
```

Test case (in notebook):

```
n = 10000000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Symbol': np.random.randint(0, 10, n),        
        'action': np.random.randint(0, 10, n),  
        'orderid': np.random.randint(0, 10, n),  
        'qty': np.random.randint(0, 10, n),  
        'status': np.random.randint(0, 10, n),  
        'price': np.random.randint(0, 10, n),  
    }
)

%%time
len(df[(df['Symbol'] == 3) & (df['action'] == 4)].values.tolist())
```

Output:

```
Wall time: 68.6 ms
99781
```

It took `68.6ms` so pretty fast I guess.